# onsubmit doesn't display text

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

Pressing the submit button doesn't display my text, but the values show up in a new url. How can I fix this? I've tried the same thing before with a different form style which worked, but I needed a new style for alignment...

```js
var passes = document.getElementById("passes").value.toString();
var slots = document.getElementById("slots").value.toString();

function showInput() {
  document.getElementById("display-input").innerHTML =
    "You entered " + passes + " for the number of passes.\n" +
    "You entered " + slots + " for the number of passes.";
  return false;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form name="form" id="form" onsubmit="showInput(); return false;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Passes: </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="passes" id="passes" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Slots: </td>
        <td><input type="number" name="slots" id="slots" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<p><span id="display-input"></span></p>
```

Comment: you have the fetch the value of input elements inside the function.. so that their value gets fetched when you click the button and not once when the page is loaded. And by the way I would prefer you used a button type=button, instead of a real submit triggering the form submit event that you cancel returning false. Just a matter of semantics.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita That's a good point, thank you. It still doesn't display anything at all though...

Comment: I did exactly what I told in my comment, inside your snippet. Just cut and paste the fetch of the values moving those 2 lines inside the function and it will just work

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Ah, I messed up with some extra statements in between, which broke something. It works now, thank you!